# Migrate all Term groups from one MMS to another MMS using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, term-store, managed-metadata-service, term-set

I have two managed metadata service applications in the Farm. I want to copy all the groups, term sets and terms with existing GUIDs from one MMS term store to another MMS term store using PowerShell. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install term set export/import tool WSP from [here](http://www.thelapointes.com/blog/WSPs/SP2010/Server/Lapointe.SharePoint.PowerShell.wsp).

Then use the following PowerShell to export and import Term Groups one by one including all content.

```
$ver = $host | select version
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

Export-SPTerms -Group (Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "https://siteconnectedtosourcemms.com").TermStores[0].Groups["TermGroupName"] -OutputFile "c:\temp\terms.xml"

Import-SPTerms -ParentTermStore (Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "https://siteconnectedtodestinationmms.com").TermStores[0] -InputFile "c:\temp\terms.xml"
```

Comment: Ok Great! But what will happened if term group with same name already exists in destination MMS. will it be skipped or overwrite or will throw error ?

Comment: If group with same name exists, it will throw error "Import-SPTerms : Failed to read from or write to database. Refresh and try again. If the problem persists, please contact the administrator."

Comment: After installing WSP, when i run Export-SPTerms and Import-SPTerms commands, it says The term 'Export-SPTerms' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet? The term ' Import-SPTerms' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet?

Comment: Did you close and reopen the PowerShell window?

Comment: Now, i am getting this error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: lcid. How i fix this?

Comment: I guess it's related to term label languages and specifically "Working Languages" of the MMS. Ensure source and destination have same "Working Languages" defined.

Answer (score 0):

What could be the solution for error you mentioned above

"Failed to read from or write to database. Refresh and try again. If the problem persists, please contact the administrator"

I am using different script but during the test I deleted terms few times and not getting this error. I want to import terms with the same IDs, how can I get rid of these IDs in the database or in other words clean up MMS database ? 
Any idea ? 
Thanks in advance. @Jussi